# Question/Answer available outside SE

Tags: discussion

If there is a question/answer situation that is available on another website, is it considered off topic or in some way duplicate?  Maybe I am missing some guideline understanding.  Is it beneficial to the community to have the question answer easily available?  Would it be good for the questioner to answer it, or copy the answer from elsewhere with a link, or leave it open for others to answer?

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange aims to be self contained resource of all questions and answers and not rely on links to external content, as links may rot/change. If there is a clear answer to a question on an external site, there is no way of flagging it as a duplicate/off-topic.

There are a couple of options, which may depend on how complicated the Q&A is.

1. You could simply post a comment with a link and let the asker investigate in the hope it will help them.
2. If there is a clear answer, you can add an answer that includes the link, along with the key content from the external site that will help solve the problem along with some explanation.

If answering with option 2, all referenced content should be properly formatted (with quote syntax highlighting) and attribution to the source/author. It's always best, when providing this kind of answer to add your own take on why the posted content will help the user solve their problem, otherwise you're not adding much value over simply posting a link in comments.

@psubsee2003's makes a very valid point in the comment:

> ...the answer must be able to stand alone without the link. The rule of thumb is, if the link were removed, would someone still be able to solve their problem with the information in the answer

Comment: While it is suggested in your 2nd option, I would be more direct in saying that the answer must be able to stand alone without the link.  The rule of thumb is, if the link were removed, would someone still be able to solve their problem with the information in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, duplicates only apply to stuff already existing within Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange.

Granted, the [help for duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) doesn't spell it out as explicity as it could be, but it seems pretty obvious.

After all, otherwise a *lot* more questions would be duplicates.